# Changing UIImagView image when iPad change its orientation

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, interface-orientation, uideviceorientation

I am using following code to change image of UIImageView when iPad orientation is changed

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    self.background=self.background_D;
    self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.background];
} 
else  if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
{
    self.background=self.background_P;
    self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.background];
} 
}
```

Everything is working fine except when I change orientation it takes a pause for a second and then changes image. Meanwhile it shows the same old image in tile format. What should I do to avoid this ?

Sumit

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use two views with both contents and implement `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and put an animation in there where you fade one view out and the other one in. If you set the timing correctly, your transition should be smooth and just done when the orientation swap is done. To animate you use either `beginAnimations:` and the associated methods or on iOS 4 upwards `[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`. http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial is a starter to animations.

An even better method would be to implement `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` which is already called inside an animation block. Here you only have to reconfigure the alpha values of your blocks and the animation will do the rest. Note that alternatively you could even implement `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` where you could hide your visible image and `willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:` where you show the other one.